# react native firebase notification cant get token

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging

i'm trying to send notification with firebase. i wanna get devices token (senderID) but when i run my code the app shut down immediately

please look at my code and tell me where is my mistake

```
import React,{useEffect} from 'react'
import { View, Text } from 'react-native'
import messaging from '@react-native-firebase/messaging'

const checkToken = async () => {
  try {
    const fcmToken = await messaging().getToken();
    if (fcmToken) {
      console.log(fcmToken);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
};

const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    checkToken()
  }, [])

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>sadasdasfdasdafsfdasfdasdafsdf</Text>
    </View>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: I just tried your code and its working for me. Did you check the logs ? any error popped up ?

Comment: that's where i stack. i got no error or something. i have no idea why thats happen

Comment: did you complete the firebase setup before running the app?

Comment: yes i did everything and im sure i did correctly

Comment: did you request permission before? and what about the user consentment?